# MetaApi Cloud API TradeError: Request canceled by timeout

Tags: metatrader5

I am getting `TradeError: Request canceled by timeout` too often when I try to hit the trade requests with MetaApi Cloud SDK. I have looked at their documentation and it is one of the errors that occur but so far I haven't found anything on the internet that specifically talks about this problem. I would like to know more about the problem and how can I tackle it.

This is the documentation for the responses from them, I am hitting the code:10012 TRADE_RETCODE_TIMEOUT error it seems.
https://metaapi.cloud/docs/client/models/metatraderTradeResponse/

If anyone knows how to tackle it, I would really appreciate it. I know these are usually network errors but if there's anything we can do from coding side to improve user experience, I would like to do it.

I am using this sdk for development
https://github.com/agiliumtrade-ai/metaapi-browser-javascript-sdk

I am just following the sdk and calling action by first initializing the connection and then calling the actions based on that connection.

This is how I am initializing connection

```
        const accounts = await metaApi.metatraderAccountApi.getAccounts();
        let account = accounts.find(a => a.login === user.login && a.type.startsWith('cloud'));

        // -> Deploy account
        await account.deploy();

        // -> Wait until connected
        await account.waitConnected();


        // -> Connect to MetaApi API
        const connection = account.getStreamingConnection();
        await connection.connect();
        await connection.waitSynchronized();

        this.account = account;
        this.connection = connection;
```

and this how I am calling an action based on connection

```
    // getting positions for example
    async getPositions() {
        return this.connection?.terminalState.positions;
    }
```

Please let me know how can I improve this so I can tackle the timeout errors because the metaAPI seems to hit them too often.

Comment: I do have no clue for this SDK but if i would encounter this i would have the init of the connection to be verified with some message or flag. This could give an idea whether it's the connection or the call for it that invokes the error.

Comment: Please clarify your question as it contains contradictory information. If the first part of your question you mention that you are getting trade error and in the second part of your question you present the code to read positions from API which is not related to the error above. I would suggest you to contact MetaApi support, they will be able to review your case and suggest what you might be doing wrong.